# Docker container cannot connect to host machine: No route to host

Tags: networking, docker, docker-compose

I've been trying to setup a docker environment using docker compose. One issue that has me stumped is that my docker containers cannot reach my host machine.

I setup a container using the following compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  webapp:
    image: ...
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

When I enter the container, I am able to ping my host machine:

```
ping ${dockerHostIP}
```

However when I  try and retrieve the home page using curl inside the container:

```
curl http://${dockerHostIP}:8080
```

I get:

```
curl: (7) Failed connect to ${dockerHostIP}:8080; No route to host
```

I cannot figure out what should be done to resolve this No route to host error. Unfortunately I need to be able to do this as the web application makes requests using its hostname internally.

Traceroute Results:

```
traceroute ${dockerHostIP}
traceroute to ${dockerHostIP} (${dockerHostIP}), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  ${dockerHostName} (${dockerHostIP})  0.039 ms !X  0.012 ms !X  0.007 ms !X
```

Comment: Really strange... what's result of `traceroute ${dockerHostIP}`?

Comment: Thanks for looking into this... I've edited the question with the traceroute results.

Comment: I guess, webapp is up and you can access `http://${dockerHostIP}:8080` from docker host? I have only two ideas: 1) webapp doesn't accept connections from container or 2) on docker host firewall blocks incoming connections from container. BTW, can you connect to host via `telnet ${dockerHostIP} 8080`?

Comment: I can access http://${dockerHostIP}:8080 from the docker host. telnet ${dockerHostIP} 8080 returns Trying ${dockerHostIP}...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: No route to host
I've tried completely disabling the firewall on my host machine systemctl firewalld stop and then spinning up the containers using docker-compose up -d and I still have the same problem

Comment: Sorry - no more ideas :-(

Comment: Well this is embarrassing... turns out it was a firewall issue. I thought I tried disabling the firewall and running, but docker-compose up wont run without firewalld up. When I opened up the port using "firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=8080/tcp" on the docker host, this resolved the issue. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 8):

To my surprise, it was actually a firewall issue in my case.

Update/Enable the tcp port [2375] on the docker host machine fixes the issue.

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=2375/tcp --permanent

sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

useful links:
1. [enter link description here](http://www.littlebigextra.com/how-to-enable-remote-rest-api-on-docker-host/)
2. [enter link description here](http://ask.xmodulo.com/open-port-firewall-centos-rhel.html)

Answer (score 0):

**Network Mode: Host**

If network mode is host, there should be no problem, but then network isolation is not in place and each container is like a service in one server, they cannot share ports, they have all the same ip address, which is the address of the host.

In Docker Compose:

```
networks:
    my-network:
        driver: host
```

**Network Mode: Bridge**

A better approach is to use the bridge network, which emulates a local network where each container has its own IP address.

In Docker Compose:

```
networks:
    my-network:
        driver: bridge
```

If you have multiple bridge networks, sometimes iptables or route tables are not properly maintained by docker, as discussed in many articles / forums:

[Why does Docker give error "connect: no route to host" when trying to connect to external resource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66067893/why-does-docker-give-error-connect-no-route-to-host-when-trying-to-connect-to)

You will find that docker0 was the network interface linked to the first default bridge (172.17.0.0), and subsequent networks are associated to virtual devices such as br-d2938602303c, br-dfd44f0535bf...

Check changing iptables to accept incoming packets from all desired docker interfaces:

BEFORE

```
[root@my-server]# iptables -S INPUT
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 8000:9999 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 2100:2199 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

AFTER

```
# Firewall configuration written by system-config-firewall
# Manual customization of this file is not recommended.
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i br-d2938602303c -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i br-dfd44f0535bf -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8000:9999 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 2100:2199 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
```

Then restart ip tables service

```
service iptables restart
```

Then I also fixed the routing table, which looks like this

```
[root@jupiter ~]# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         static.129.95.9 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eno1
static.129.95.9 0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 eno1
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 eno1
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.18.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-d2938602303c
172.19.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-dfd44f0535bf
```

Useful links:

https://superuser.com/questions/1460441/connection-refused-using-host-docker-internal-in-docker-container

https://www.baeldung.com/linux/docker-connecting-containers-to-host

https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/i5es7f/no_route_to_host_but_successful_google_ping/

[Why does Docker give error "connect: no route to host" when trying to connect to external resource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66067893/why-does-docker-give-error-connect-no-route-to-host-when-trying-to-connect-to)