# Docker container cannot connect to Host Machine

Tags: docker, docker-compose

i tried to deploy some containers to a new CentOS7 VM (newest docker version) with docker-compose:

- ASP.NET Application
- Mongo
- Nginx Reverse Proxy
- Lets Encrypt Sidecar for Nginx

The connection between the containers works fine. But my ASP.NET Application has to make a request to itself using the public domain name. It fails and when I make a curl request inside the container it fails with `No route to Host`. Note: I am not using localhost or so.

I found another post: [Docker container cannot connect to host machine: No route to host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43879637/docker-container-cannot-connect-to-host-machine-no-route-to-host)

It seemed to be firewall problem in this case. So I also tried to add firewall rules, but it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the container X, where your ASP net container is running, does need to contact your app using the domain. Assuming, you either use domain.dev in development or domain.tld, it you can pass "host" arguments to the container on start ( or in docker compose ways ) to bind that domain to either localhost, so --host domain.tld:127.0.0.1 or the actual IP of the container ( the private one ).

The latter one needs you to actually use docker-networks and give every container a static IP in the docker network, so you know the ASP net container IP prior starting it. You can of course do some docker-socket mount + docker inspect magic in the container, but that is far to overblown for development purposes.

References: 
 - docker host entries: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#managing-etchosts
 - docker networks https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#network-settings

And in docker compose:
 - docker host entries: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#extra_hosts
 - networks: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#networks

Hint: i would strongly encourage you to use docker-compose.

Alternativ ways:
you can also use the service-name as the domain in your container, since this is automatically resolving to the container IP, so assuming your ASP net container is named "app" in the docker-compose file ( the service ), you can access it using app in the container.

Comment: As I said I have to make a request to the container itself, so I can just use localhost. But it does not explain the problem.

Comment: then check your firewall. This comes from a different bridge which will not be localhost and will trigger your firewall. You did not write anything else i have writte, neither mapping hostnames nor anything else. Nevertheless, good look