# Why does Docker give error "connect: no route to host" when trying to connect to external resource?

Tags: docker

When trying to connect to an external resource from a container, I get the following error:

```
[00] app: error: dial tcp {my-ip}:5432: connect: no route to host, try --help
```

I have double-checked all my configs and docker-compose files and rebuilt everything and still, the error persists.

(In my case this was a GoLang server in a local container attempting to connect to an aws-hosted PostgreSQL database)

Comment: Have you checked your firewall ? can you check with telnet 10.1.20.64:443 to see if you can reach there?

Comment: Can you please share the output of this command docker network ls

Comment: NETWORK ID     NAME      DRIVER    SCOPE
5f4d91fcf131   bridge    bridge    local
9fb199f0e200   host      host      local
d476bbffe52f   none      null      local

@Ashok

Answer (score 23):

Try to remove the other bridged network other than the default one and try to pull the image again and it worked for me.

```
> docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                       DRIVER              SCOPE
b139fe9f89e3        bridge                     bridge              local
e5dfbbee314v        network-1                  bridge              local
6ruvy84eg56n        network-2                  bridge              local
1e0ccbec292a        host                       host                local
e1c69bce4r56        none                       null                local

> docker network rm e5 6r

> docker pull private-repo:port-number/your/image:latest
```

Comment: I'm having only the default networks, one workaround I found was to disable kubernetes on docker for desktop and restart docker again manually.

Comment: worked for me, had a couple of bridged networks. No idea why this was the issue

Comment: This worked like a charm for me, thanks! Was banging my head against a wall until I found this.

Comment: This worked for me. I had to remove networks created by docker-compose file. Thanks!

Comment: But what if you need them as well? If you have a large server with more than one docker network, this is not a possibility. It may be just a matter of adding a route entry or iptable rule to fix the issue.